# Failed to evaluate expression with spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, csrf, self-signed

I have a Spring rest service, and I'm trying to add security to it. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/10/31/securing-a-restful-web-service-with-spring-security-3-1-part-3/#config), but when I try to access the service directly I get the following error:

> There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error,
>   status=500). Failed to evaluate expression 'ROLE_USER'

Here's my security configuration:

`webSecurityConfig.xml`

```
<http entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
      <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_USER"/>

      <form-login
         authentication-success-handler-ref="mySuccessHandler"
         authentication-failure-handler-ref="myFailureHandler"
      />

      <logout />
   </http>

   <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler"
      class="com.eficid.cloud.security.rest.AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
   <beans:bean id="myFailureHandler" class=
     "org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler"/>


      <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
          <user-service>
            <user name="temp" password="temp" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
          </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
      </authentication-manager>
```

`SpringSecurityConfig`:

```
public class SpringSecurityConfig {

    public SpringSecurityConfig() {
        super();
    }

}
```

I'm also getting this error when trying to use curl to log in:

```
{
"timestamp":1460399841286,
"status":403,"error":"Forbidden",
"message":"Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.",
"path":"/spring-security-rest/login"
}
```

Do I need to add the csrf token manually to the command? The service has a self-signed certificate, if that makes any difference.

Comment: You don't seem to have an HTTP Session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `hasRole('ROLE_USER')` in the intercept-url element.

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
```

See the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) for the other expressions, that you can use.

Comment: Hai @Evgeni. When i do login along with 'X-CSRF-TOKEN' my login is successfully executed. But after that when i send some request i get 'Could not verify the provided CSRF token because your session was not found.' message. I have given proper patterns and access in my given code. Can you please suggest anything. Thanks in advance

Comment: @HaseebWali I suggest you ask another question and provide more details, like your configuration...

Answer (score 4):

If you don't need CRF to be enabled, then you can disable it in webSecurityConfig.xml file like below:

```
        <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.html" access="hasRole('ANONYMOUS')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')"/>
        <!-- This form is a default form that used to login  
            <http-basic/>
         -->
         <form-login login-page="/login.html"/>
         <csrf disabled="true"/>
    </http>
```

If CSRF is enabled, you have to include a _csrf.token in the page you want to login or logout.The below code needs to be added to the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
            value="${_csrf.token}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

**Spring security blocks POST requests.**

To enable it you can either:

- Add after all you forms requests :

`<input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" class="form-control" />`

(For example: 
 `<form id="computerForm" action="addComputer" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                            value="${_csrf.token}" class="form-control" />`

)

- Or if you use anotation, you can allow POST directly in your code by adding the **csrf().disable** on your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter (I havent found the xml equivalent yet) :

  `@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception   {
       http.authorizeRequests()
         .antMatchers("/admin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
         .and().formLogin()
         .csrf().disable()
  ;}`